# Variable Scope Within Object Heirarchy

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

Im going through the '[You Dont Know Javascript](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS)' series (which is awesome btw). Going through the 'Scope' chapter & its '[building metaphor](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch1.md#building-on-metaphors)' , shouldn't the following Js code run because one obj is within the scope of its parent object?

```
var aaa = {  // global obj
  a : 'a',
  bbb : { // child obj
    b : 'b',
    ccc : {  // child's child obj
      c : 'c',
      dfunc : function () {
        console.log (a);
        console.log (b);
        console.log (c);
      }
    }
  }
}

aaa.bbb.ccc.dfunc(); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Upon run, I get the above commented error.

Comment: Scope is per function, so you got two scopes there, the global scope, and the scope of `dfunc`

Comment: `a` is not defined but `aaa.a` is, `b` is not defined but `aaa.bbb.b` is, etc...

Comment: `a` isn't defined locally or globally for `dfunc` function

Comment: Only variables and named functions have scope. Properties of objects do not have scope. You have only one variable in your example called `aaa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReferenceError: a is not defined is Correct

in your code only `aaa` is define and everything else is the property of aaa object

```
var aaa = {  // global obj
  a : 'a',
  bbb : { // child obj
    b : 'b',
    ccc : {  // child's child obj
      c : 'c',
      dfunc : function () {
        console.log (a); // its a property  of aaa 
        console.log (b);
        console.log (c);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Function has only it's **own scope** and **global scope** but Function inside function has main parent function variable access which is not same as for object.

Try this:

```
var aaa = {  // global obj
  a : 'a',
  bbb : { // child obj
    b : 'b',
    ccc : {  // child's child obj
      c : 'c',
      dfunc : function () {
        console.log (aaa.a);
        console.log (aaa.bbb.b);
        console.log (this.c);
      }
    }
  }
}

aaa.bbb.ccc.dfunc();
```

Comment: Then how does the building metaphor work here. I guess, the author is referring to the prototype inheritance here...

Answer (score 1):

You can use prototypal inheritance..

The following is the same but the `Object.create()` inherits the properties of the object it was created from via the prototype tree.

```
var aaa = {};
var bbb = Object.create(aaa); // create with the properties of aaa
var ccc = Object.create(bbb); // create with the properties of bbb

aaa.a = "a1";  // add new properties to all
bbb.b = "b2";
ccc.c = "c3";

// not needed but 
aaa.bbb = bbb;  // just to be the same reference bbb in aaa
bbb.ccc = ccc;  // and ccc in bbb

aaa.saySomething = function(){  // add the function to the base object
    console.log(this.a);
    console.log(this.b);
    console.log(this.c);
}
// call from the top gets all properties
ccc.saySomething(); // outputs a1 b2 c3

// call from the middle
bbb.saySomething(); // outputs a1 b2 undefined 
                    // this does not have access to ccc

// call from the bottom
aaa.saySomething(); // outputs a1 undefined undefined 
                    // this doe not have access to bbb and ccc
```